# avro schema evolution - Update schema of avro generic record via copy/deepcopy/reflect?

Tags: java, kotlin, avro

Assume I have two compatible avro schemas:

- Foo(v1) contains *required* field `foo`
- Foo(v2) contains *required* field `foo` and *optional* field `bar`

We can assume, that I can read data written with `v1` using `v2`, because the schemas are compatible and the new field `bar` will automatically be set to `null`.

A schema compatibility check confirms this:

```java
SchemaCompatibility.checkReaderWriterCompatibility(v2,v1)
```

```
SchemaPairCompatibility{
   result:SchemaCompatibilityResult{compatibility:COMPATIBLE, incompatibilities:[]}, 
   readerSchema: {
      "type":"record","name":"Foo",
      "fields":[{"name":"foo","type":"string"},
         {"name":"bar","type":["null","string"],"default":null}]
   }, 
   writerSchema:{
      "type":"record","name":"Foo",
      "fields":[{"name":"foo","type":"string"}]
   }, 
   description:Reader schema can always successfully decode data written using the writer schema.
}
```

**Question:**

When I create a `GenericData.Record` of `v1` via `GenericData.Record(v1)` and `put("foo","value")` - (how) can I apply schema-evolution/migration to automatically create a record based on `v2` containing the values: `foo="value"; bar=null`?

Scope: I know how to achieve this using encoder/decoder and reader/writer schema. The question is: Can I do this manually, directly on the level of a record, without encoding it first. I tried combinations of `newRecord` and `deepCopy`, but those didn't work.